# Find a set $X$ such that $X\cap P(X)\neq\emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

- Find a set $X$ such that $X\cap P(X)\neq\emptyset$

My answer is: Take $X=\left\{ \emptyset \right\}$. Then, $\left\{ \emptyset \right\}\cap P(\left\{ \emptyset \right\})=\left\{ \emptyset \right\}\neq \emptyset$. So we are done.

**Can you check my answer and proof-writing?**

Comment: What is $P(X)$?

Comment: But isn't $P(\{\emptyset\})=\{\{\emptyset\}\}$, then $\emptyset$ is really something different than $\{\emptyset\}$? Also, I think this has no solution, since If $X$ is any set with some elements $x$, then $P(X)$ is set of subsets with elements $x$.

Comment: @packetpacket Power set

Comment: @MichalDvořák, no $P(\{\emptyset \})$ is the power set of the set containing the emptyset, which is a one-element set. so, the power set would be $\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset \} \}$, which is two elements.

Comment: Any nonempty set $X$ will work.

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: @MichalDvořák $P(\left\{ \emptyset \right\})=\left\{ \emptyset ,\left\{ \emptyset\right\} \right\}$?

Comment: @pointguard0 not every non empty set will work. For example, let $X=\{1\}$.

Comment: What is there to check? You have to have faith in yourself.

Comment: @pointguard0 no, it will not. For instance, $A=\{1\}, P(A) = \{\emptyset, \{1\}\}$ and $$A \cap P(A) = \emptyset$$ because $1 \notin P(A)$. In the OP's example, the set chosen was a set containing a set (which happened to be empty). I believe the OP's solution is the only solution.

Comment: @pointguard0 Yes you are right. Every non empty set wiil not work

Comment: yes you are right guys, not every non empty set will work!

Comment: Thanks for comments...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any non-empty transitive set would work (if $X$ is transitive then $X \subseteq P(X)$), and in particular any non-zero ordinal would work, and in particular any non-zero natural number would work, and in particular $1 = \{\varnothing\}$ would work, which is your example.

Another collection of solutions is the van Neumann universes with non-zero finite index.

Also, more generally, the transitive closure of any non-empty set would work.

---

$X \cap P(X) \ne \varnothing$ is equivalent to an element of $X$ being a subset of $X$.

If we start with any set $X$, we could pick any subset $Y \subseteq X$, and then $Y$ would also be a subset of $Z := X \cup \{Y\}$, but now $Y \in Z$ also, so $Z$ would work.

In particular, taking $Y = X$ gives us $Z := X \cup \{X\}$, i.e. the successor of any set works, and in particular the successor of the empty set works, which is also again your example.

Comment: Even more generally (_and_ more obviously) than the first two points, any set that contains $\varnothing$ would work.

Comment: That's taking $Y = \varnothing$ lol, but good point.

Comment: In particular the power set of any set would work...

Answer (score 0):

Only one thing you can be sure of when constructing a power set for some set $X$ that $\emptyset \in P(X)$ and $X\in P(X)$.

So, for our solution we want something to be both in $P(X)$ and $X$ itself. But $X\in X$ is restricted by axiom of foundation. So anything in the form $\{\emptyset,a,b,c,1,2,3,...\}$ would be a solution.